# "no method named `paginate` found for struct `sea_orm::Select` in the current scope"

Tags: generics, rust, pagination, findall, sea-orm

I am using a generic function for my findAll on all of my entities. Now that I try to implement pagination it can't find the method paginate.

I assume I am missing some generic parameters.

This is my current approach:

```
use sea_orm::{DatabaseConnection, EntityTrait, PaginatorTrait};

use crate::dto::pagination::{Paginated, Pagination};

pub(crate) async fn get_all<T>(
    conn: &DatabaseConnection,
    pagination: Pagination,
) -> Result<Paginated<T::Model>, Error>
where
    T: EntityTrait,
{
    let pages = T::find().paginate(conn, pagination.limit);

    let entities: Vec<T::Model> = pages.fetch_page(pagination.page).await?;

    let paginated = Paginated {
        data: entities,
        page: pagination.page,
        total: pages.num_pages().await?,
        limit: pagination.limit,
    };

    Ok(paginated)
}
```

This was my method before implementing pagination:

```
pub(crate) async fn get_all<T>(conn: &DatabaseConnection) -> Result<Vec<T::Model>, Error>
where
    T: EntityTrait,
{
    let entities = T::find().all(conn).await?;

    Ok(entities)
}
```

The entities are generated by seaorm and this is how i would try to use the method:

```
generic_repository::get_all::<myEntity::Entity>(&state.conn, pagination).await?;
```

Compiler shows:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `paginate` found for struct `sea_orm::Select` in the current scope
  --> src\repository\generic_repository.rs:28:27
   |
28 |     let pages = T::find().paginate(conn, pagination.limit);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Select<T>`

error: aborting due to previous error; 8 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `replaces_my_appname-api` (bin "replaces_my_appname-api") due to 2 previous errors; 8 warnings emitted
Process finished with exit code 101
```

Comment: Have you imported `sea_orm::PaginatorTrait`?

Comment: @trust_nickol yes my imports are

`use sea_orm::{DatabaseConnection, EntityTrait, PaginatorTrait};
use crate::dto::pagination::{Paginated, Pagination};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add some traits for the model too:

```
use sea_orm::{DatabaseConnection, EntityTrait, PaginatorTrait};

use crate::dto::pagination::{Paginated, Pagination};

pub(crate) async fn get_all<T, M>(
    conn: &DatabaseConnection,
    pagination: Pagination,
) -> Result<Paginated<T::Model>, Error>
where
    T: EntityTrait<Model=M>,
    M: FromQueryResult + Sized + Send + Sync,
{
    let pages = T::find().paginate(conn, pagination.limit);

    let entities: Vec<T::Model> = pages.fetch_page(pagination.page).await?;

    let paginated = Paginated {
        data: entities,
        page: pagination.page,
        total: pages.num_pages().await?,
        limit: pagination.limit,
    };

    Ok(paginated)
}
```